# Absolute Value Inequalities for proving a limit

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I am trying to prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}$ $f(x) = 2x^2 -5x + 2=2$. This is what my incorrect work looks like: https://prnt.sc/1rylg4l

I know delta must be positive since it is an upper bound on distance/absolute value and therefore I must have made a mistake when solving the inequality.

I know that $|x|<1$, therefore, $-1 < x < 1 = -2 < 2x < 2 = -7 < 2x-5 < -3$.
I am trying to find the correct bound on $|2x-5|$.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the math in your question with [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Your analysis is good, except that you used the equal sign  $=$ to represent implies  $\implies$.  In general, if $-7 < f(x) < -3$, then $3 < |f(x)| < 7.$

Comment: What is the limit you are trying to prove?

Comment: @amWhy From OP's comment in an answer: https://prnt.sc/1rylg4l

Comment: $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}$ $f(x) = 2x^2 -5x + 2=2$

Comment: Please include that in your question, @Malek.

Comment: @soupless, if it's not in the question post, that is a problem. Surely you can see that much.

Comment: I added the screenshot of the work + the limit I'm trying to prove. Sorry about the confusion, this is my first time using math stack exchange.

Comment: I'm usually lenient with newcomers posting links to images to work but in this case .... no....   You have to figure some other way to display the work you do.  That link is utterly unreadable and unusable and inaccessible.

Comment: If $|x| < 1$ then $-1 < x < 1\implies -2 < 2x < 2\implies -7 < 2x - 5 < -3$ as you have noticed.

So $2x -5 < 0$ and $|2x-5| = -(2x-5)$.

And $-7 < 2x - 5 < -3 \implies 7 > -(2x-5) > 3$ and so $3 < |2x-5| < 7$.  But why are you trying to find this?  Will this help you find the limit you want?

Comment: This is great, thank you! I'm not trying to find the limit but rather prove it. Essentially I set delta to be the min(1 and another number which I don't know yet(most often involving ε) and by setting delta to be at least 1 and I know that |x| < delta then I know that |x| < 1 and therefore |2x - 5| < 7. This is helpful because I can set |x|*|2x-5| to be < delta * 7. This tells me that the other value for delta that I was looking for is ε/7 and therefore ε/7 *7 = ε. Proving the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|2x^2- 5x+ 2- 2|= |2x^2-5x|= |x||2x- 5|$ as you have.   You want $|x||2x-5|< \epsilon$ for x "small enough"- i.e. close enough to 0.  Notice that your |x| is already of the form "|x- 0|", it is the |2x- 5| that is the problem.

Yes, since we are taking x close to 0 we can certainly assume that -1< x< 1 so -2< 2x< 2 and -7< 2x- 5< -3.  Both bounds are negative but 3< |2x- 5|< 5.

That is we can assume that |2x- 5|< 5 so that $|x||2x- 5|< 5|x|< \epsilon$.

So we can take $\delta< \frac{\epsilon}{5}$.

Comment: This is great, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, $-7 < 2x-5 < -3$, meaning $|2x-5| < 7$. The bound can't be less than 7 because then you're excluding values.

Comment: Thank you for your response! What confused me is that I was looking for an abs(2x-5) being < than something. https://prnt.sc/1rylg4l in this problem to fix my mystake, would I be looking at abs(2x-5)>7 and therefore have abs(x) times abs(2x-5) < delta times 7 = delta times epsilon/7 = epsilon? Sorry if this sounds confusing, Im not sure how to write proper notation on a keyboard.

Comment: @MalekHaddad For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

You can also approach it as follows.

Let $0 < |x - 0| < \delta_{\varepsilon}$. Then we conclude that
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - 2| & = |2x^{2} - 5x|\\\\
& \leq 2|x|^{2} + 5|x|\\\\
& < 2\delta^{2}_{\varepsilon} + 5\delta_{\varepsilon} := \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: This is not how I usually prove limits, but it's a great way to approach it. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome ! I am glad I could help.

Comment: @MalekHaddad You can choose my answer if you think it deserves.